# Normal matrices and projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

Just need a hint on following exercise:

> Let $P \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) $ be a normal matrix such that $P^9=P^8$ . Prove $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What is **for you** an "orthogonal projection"?

Comment: My instructor characterized orthogonal projectors like Meyer did in his Matrix Analysis. i.e. P is an orthogonal projector if $P^2=P$, or $ R(P)$ perpendicular to $N(P)$

Answer (score 1):

The hint is to (unitarily) diagonalize; or to use the Spectral Theorem (both things are the same).

*Orthogonal projection* usually means $P^*P=P $, which is more often written as $P^2=P=P^*$.

Comment: Thanks again, Martín, feeling embarrased, cause i've asked too many questions already (and I've got more) :S

Comment: That's what this site is for, so don't worry. Consider also upvoting those questions you find interesting and those answers you find useful, that's how the stack exchange works.

Comment: Sure, i'll do it! Hoping this question helps another person.

Answer (score 0):

The result holds in any Hilbert space. If $P$ is normal then
$$\|Px\|=\|P^*x\|$$
follows from looking at squares and use normality.
But then $\ker P = \ker P^*$. Now if
$$P^* P x=0$$ then obviously $\|Px\|^2 = (x,P^*Px)=0$ so also $Px=0$.
So $\ker P = \ker P^*P = \ker P^2$. This generalizes then to 
$$\ker P = \ker P^2 = ... = \ker P^8$$
So $P^9=P^8$ means $P^8(1-P)=0$ or by what has just been said $P(1-P)=0$. In other words $P^2=P$ is a projection. Since $P(1-P)=0$ also $P^*(1-P)=0$ from which we deduce that $P=P^*$ so $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Wow, i didn't see it in that way. Really interesting, though i hadn't even seen Hilbert Spaces!